# Send image from my server to API using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, image

Let us say there is an image on server A, my server is B, and G cloud server is C.

Now, I want to send this image on server A to server C using an API call from server B. I am able to download image on my server (server B), how can I send this image to server C to get the image link (the API returns the image link). I want it to be done without page refresh.

Methodology I am following is

1. Download image from server A to server B
2. Send image from server B to server C
3. Get cloud link from server C and display the image with new url

I am using NodeJS + express in backend

Can this be done with FormData() without using input type file?